# Sending outgoing mail from multiple e-mail accounts (of different domains hosted on the same server) using sSMTP

Tags: email, sendmail, webmail, ssmtp

I'm hosting multiple domains in my public html folder of an ubuntu-nginx vps server. And I currently have my 'ssmtp.conf' file set up successfully to send outgoing mail(contact, registration, verification, forgot password etc using php 'mail()') from one of those domains, say, **example1.com**.

Would there be any way to make some modifications on the 'ssmtp.conf' file such that mail can be sent from the e-mail accounts pertaining to the other domains as well?(**mail@example2.com** or **mail@example3.com**, for instance).

Thanks in advance.

My current ssmtp.conf file looks like this:

```
#
# Config file for sSMTP sendmail
#
# The person who gets all mail for userids < 1000
# Make this empty to disable rewriting.
root=mail@example1.com

# The place where the mail goes. The actual machine name is required no 
# MX records are consulted. Commonly mailhosts are named mail.domain.com
mailhub=smtp.example1.com:25

# Where will the mail seem to come from?
rewriteDomain=example1.com

# The full hostname
hostname=example1.com

# Are users allowed to set their own From: address?
# YES - Allow the user to specify their own From: address
# NO - Use the system generated From: address
FromLineOverride=YES

AuthUser=mail@example1.com
AuthPass=password-for-mail@example1.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a SMTP library like SwiftMailer in PHP to send mails via SMTP to the mail server instead of `mail()` function. This way you can use arbitrary `From` addresses in e-mails.